# Modifying an element in a dataframe by checking a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to categorise elements in a list using a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'beach': ['beach', 'sand', 'coast'], 'package': ['package', 'inclusive']}
```

given dataframe:

```
Keyword                         |cat |
--------------------------------|----|
beach holiday                   |    |
package beach holiday           |    |
inclusive beach holiday         |    |
```

I want to check that if an element is in the dictionary it applies the keyword to the category column e.g.:

```
Keyword                         |cat |
--------------------------------|----|
beach holiday                   |beach  |
package beach holiday           |package|
inclusive package beach holiday |package|
```

I have attempted with the following code:

```
df = get_csv(csv)
mydict = {'beach': ['beach', 'sand', 'coast'], 'package': ['package', 'inclusive']}

for key in mydict.keys():
    item = key
    if item in mydict[key]:
        target_cats = item
        find_keywords = lambda kw: [s for s in kw.split() if s in target_cats]

        df.loc[:, 'cat_list'] = df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: find_keywords(x))
        for i in range(1, 4):
            df.loc[:, 'cat{0}'.format(i)] = df['cat_list'].apply(lambda x: x[i-1] if len(x) >= i else '')

print(df)
df.to_csv('kuoniTesting.csv')
```

However this just gives an empty category list, the code to check against a list works, how do i modify this to use a dictionary?

```
target_cats = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': ['cat dog cow', 'cat dog', 'dog sheep']})
find_keywords = lambda kw: [s for s in kw.split() if s in target_cats]

df.loc[:, 'cat_list'] = df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: find_keywords(x))
for i in range(1, 4):
    df.loc[:, 'cat{0}'.format(i)] = df['cat_list'].apply(lambda x: x[i-1] if 
    len(x) >= i else '')

 Keyword      cat_list         cat1 cat2 cat3
  0  cat dog cow  [cat, dog, cow]  cat  dog  cow
  1      cat dog       [cat, dog]  cat  dog     
  2    dog sheep            [dog]  dog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap `values` in dictionary with keys, but it return multiple values:

```
mydict = {'beach': ['beach', 'sand', 'coast'], 'package': ['package', 'inclusive']}
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in mydict.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'sand': 'beach', 'package': 'package', 'beach': 'beach', 
 'inclusive': 'package', 'coast': 'beach'}

find_keywords = lambda kw: [d[s] for s in kw.split() if s in d.keys()]
df['cat_list'] = df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: find_keywords(x))
print (df)
                   Keyword          cat_list
0            beach holiday           [beach]
1    package beach holiday  [package, beach]
2  inclusive beach holiday  [package, beach]
```

And for new columns:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['cat_list'].values.tolist(), columns=['cat1','cat2']))
print (df)
                   Keyword          cat_list     cat1   cat2
0            beach holiday           [beach]    beach   None
1    package beach holiday  [package, beach]  package  beach
2  inclusive beach holiday  [package, beach]  package  beach
```